# Accessing asp.net hidden field control inside iframe using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iframe, captcha

I have used Iframe for loading Captcha image in my Default.aspx page. In Captcha.aspx file, I have generated random number and assigned the random number to a hidden field.

**Captcha.aspx:**

```
<asp:hiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnCaptcha"/>
```

**Captcha.aspx.vb:**

hdnCaptcha.Value = randomNumber

**Default.aspx:**

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="Captcha.aspx"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('ifrm');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var captcha = innerDoc.getElementById('hdnCaptcha').value;
```

The hidden field captcha value always returns null. How to access hidden field value from Iframe source page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET generates IDs in the resulting html, which are longer then what you see in your aspx markup. So what you could do is:

1. Insert real client id into the javascript. This will work only if the js code is in the aspx file itself, not in a separate js file:

   ```
   var captcha = innerDoc.getElementById('<%= hdnCaptcha.ClientID %>').value;
   ```

   Since you are dealing with iframe that might not be your option. Then refer to
2. Set the ID mode of hidden field to static. That will force ASP.NET to output id as-is, no additions. Mind that in this case it is your job to guarantee that there is only one control with this ID on the iframe page:

   ```
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnCaptcha" ClientIDMode="Static" />
   ```

Comment: I have tried everything except ClientIDMode="Static" option. Is this technique will collide with ajax update panel control?

Comment: @RGS, it should be fine, as long as you stick to the rule of unique id on the page. And even if you don't - you may get away with this, page won't crash, just javascript is not guaranteed to work correctly with multiple equal IDs